# In JavaScript, if an event trigger is declared on an HTML element and its ancestor, which fires first?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

There are two `onchange` triggers: one on the INPUT and one from the FORM containing the INPUT.

```
document.getElementByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('change',funcForm);
document.getElementByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('change',funcInput);
```

1. does `funcForm` or `funcInput` fire first?
2. is this behavior defined and consistent?
3. if `e.stopPropagation()` is issued on the first firing trigger, does the second fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input's handlers should be triggered first and then the event should bubble up the DOM hierarchy if it bubbles. From the [DOM Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling):

> The event is dispatched to its target EventTarget and any event listeners found there are triggered. Bubbling events will then trigger any additional event listeners found by following the EventTarget's parent chain upward
>   [...]
>   Any event handler may choose to prevent further event propagation by calling the `stopPropagation` method of the `Event` interface. If any `EventListener` calls this method, all additional `EventListeners` on the current `EventTarget` will be triggered but bubbling will cease at that level. Only one call to `stopPropagation` is required to prevent further bubbling.

The second paragraph applies to `stopPropagation` and says that if the listener on the `input` calls `e.stopPropagation()`, then the event should not get up to the `<form>`. However, any remaining listeners on the `<input>` **will** see the change event, `stopPropagation` just keeps the event from bubbling up the tree any further than the level at which `stopPropagation` is called.

Furthermore, the [change event does bubble](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> **change**
>   The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.
>
> - Bubbles: Yes

Comment: thanks - did you see #3: does e.stopPropagation() stop the second trigger from firing?

Comment: @cc: I just pulled in the relevant section of the standard for `stopPropagation`.

Comment: to clarify, `stopPropagation` prevents firing triggers on the same eventTarget (eg, change) attached to ancestors to element

Comment: @cc: Yes, `stopPropagation` keeps the event from going up the tree. But, if there are three listeners attached to the `<input>` and the first one calls `e.stopPropagation()`, the other two will still get the event but the `<form>` won't.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if the event handler is set for the *capturing* phase or the *bubbling* phase. The `addEventListener` function has a third parameter called `useCapture` which defaults to false. If `useCapture` is true, the ancestor element *captures* the event on its way down the DOM tree and fires its handler first. If `useCapture` is false (default), the event travels down the DOM tree to the event target and the child element fires its handler first, then the event *bubbles* up to the ancestor.

So the way you currently have it: `funcInput` will fire first; the behavior is defined and consistent; and `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent `funcForm` and any other event handlers from firing.

Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener for more information.

Comment: is this a correct summary?: the following will fire: 1) INPUT funcInput, 2) INPUT funcForm, 3) FORM funcForm - and if 1 calls stopPropagation, 2 and 3 will not be called.

Comment: It's worth noting that IE<=8 does not support listeners in the capturing phase.

Comment: this is what I found: 1) INPUT funcInput, 2) INPUT funcForm.  if funcInput calls stopPropagation then INPUT funcForm is _not_ called